# Converting pandas column of comma-separated strings into integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that contains a column with comma separated values. I would like to convert the string values in that column to integers.

I am newish to coding in general so a brief explanation of what is happening would be massively appreciated. If you have time.

I have tried the following code.

```
df['col3'].str.strip(',').astype(int)

df
col1 col2 col3
1    x    12,123
2    x    1,123
3    y    45,998

df
col1 col2 col3
1    x    12123
2    x    1123
3    y    45998
```

Comment: do not add SOLVED to the title of the question, in SO it is enough to mark a response as correct. And if you want to thank the best is to give an upvote and for that you must gain reputation.

Comment: Did you create this `DataFrame` with `pd.read_csv` or `pd.read_table`? Then you can bypass all of this by adding `thousands=','` as an argument to those methods.

Comment: @ALollz I used pd.read_csv. How would I use the thousands argument? Thank you for helping.

Comment: @eyllanesc apologies. Thanks for teaching me forum etiquette.

Comment: Add it within the parentheses of your method: `pd.read_csv('your_file_name', thousands=',')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your solution should actually be:

```
df['col3'] = df.col3.str.split(',').str.join('').astype(int)

    col1 col2   col3
0     1    x  12123
1     2    x   1123
2     3    y  45998
```

As `str.strip` only  strips from the left and right sides.

**Explanation**

- `str`: Allows for vectorized string functions for Series
- `split`: Will split each element in the list according to some pattern, `,` in this case
- `join`: will join elements in the now Series of lists with a passed delimeter, `''` here as you want to create `ints`.

And finally `.astype(int)` to turn each string into an integer

Comment: Star! Thank you so much. Solved my question.

Answer (score 8):

There are already answers to this question but , i would like to add a another solution:

**DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
   col1 col2    col3
0     1    x  12,123
1     2    x   1,123
2     3    y  45,998
```

Try simplest by using `str.replace` method and you are all done:

```
>>> df['col3'] = df['col3'].str.replace(",", "")
# df['col3'] = df['col3'].str.replace(",", "").astype(int) <- cast to int
>>> df
   col1 col2   col3
0     1    x  12123
1     2    x   1123
2     3    y  45998
```

OR

another using `df.replace` along with regex method as Regex substitution is performed under the hood with `re.sub`. The rules for substitution for `re.sub` are the same.

```
>>> df['col3'] = df['col3'].replace(',', '', regex=True)
>>> df
   col1 col2   col3
0     1    x  12123
1     2    x   1123
2     3    y  45998
```

Answer (score 2):

Brief explanation:

```
df['col3'].str.strip(',').str.join('').astype(int)
```

- `df['col3']` generates a `pandas.Series` from the values of `col3`
- `_______.str` can be understood as a cast-to-string, usually means you would like to use a string method to the contents of your series
- `_____.str.strip(',')` uses the `strip` method: break a string into substrings, using the separator provided as the parameter used to distinguish when one substring ends and when the next one begins
- `_____.str.strip(',').str.join('')` takes the substrings generated by the split and concatenates them together (effectively you're just removing the separator)
- `____.astype(int)` casts your result to an int

Credit to nixon on including the `join` to generate the actual desired output. Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: Brilliant! That's very kind of you for providing such a great explanation.

Comment: `cast-to-string`, not quite, that just means you are querying the "string accessor" which is the gateway to string operations on series.

Comment: agree on the not quite, hence the 'can be understood' preamble hehe

Answer (score 0):

All the answers talk about solving it after the data is read from the source like csv or excel. Another way to look at the problem is to normalize the data during reading from the source. Here is how you do when using read_csv or read_excel

```
pd.read_csv('your_file_name', thousands=',')
pd.read_excel('your/file/name', thousands=',')
```

See panda documentation [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)